# $x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_3x_4 + x_2x_3x_4 \leq C(x_1^2 +x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2)^{3/2}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_4$ be real numbers. I wish to show that there exists a constant $C$ such that

$$x_1x_2x_3 + x_1x_2x_4 + x_1x_3x_4 + x_2x_3x_4 \leq C(x_1^2 +x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2)^{3/2}$$

Moreover, I want to find the smallest such constant.

This must involve some identity with symmetric polynomials, but I haven't been able to get any to work. I've tried the usual (Newton, Muirhead, etc.)

Comment: Hint: So long as you are not after the optimal $C$, it is enough to take a single term on the left. Then you get the similar inequality for the other terms by permuting the variables, and the final $C$ will be four times the one for a single term. Moreover, to prove it with $x_1x_2x_3$ on the left, you can drop the $x_4$ term on the right. Take the cube root. Do you recognize the inequality then?

Comment: Another approach is to use homogeneity to restrict yourself to the case where $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^3+x_4^2=1$ and use compactness. But since you use the algebra-precalculus tag, I suspect you don't have know about compactness yet.

Comment: Yes. Actually, you have a similar inequality between geometric mean and mean square which is more appropriate, but that follows from the AM-GM inequality applied to the squared terms.

Comment: Thus, I get $x_1^2 x_2^2 x_2^3 ≤(x_2^1+x_2^2+x_2^3)^3$, and we take square roots.

Comment: I think you mixed up some sub- and superscript. And you forgot to divide by 3 somewhere (the mean of three numbers, after all). But yes, you have got it.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1=x_2=x_3=x_4=1$ we get $C\geq\frac{1}{2}$.

We'll prove that $C=\frac{1}{2}$ is valid.

We need to prove that:
$$(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\geq2( x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)$$
and since the left side does not depend on replacing $x_i\rightarrow-x_i$,

it's enough to prove the last inequality for non-negative variables.

In another hand,
 $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2\geq\frac{2}{3}(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)$$
it's just
$$(x_1-x_2)^2+(x_1-x_3)^2+(x_1-x_4)^2+(x_2-x_3)^2+(x_2-x_4)^2+(x_3-x_4)^2\geq0.$$
thus, it remains to prove that
$$\left(\frac{2}{3}(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}\geq$$
$$\geq2( x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4)$$ or
$$\sqrt{\frac{x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_1x_4+x_2x_3+x_2x_4+x_3x_4}{6}}\geq\sqrt[3]{\frac{x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+x_1x_3x_4+x_2x_3x_4}{4}}$$
and see here:
[How to prove this inequality $\sqrt{\frac{ab+bc+cd+da+ac+bd}{6}}\geq \sqrt[3]{{\frac{abc+bcd+cda+dab}{4}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197955/)

Done!