# Generalized AM-GM Inequality

Tags: geometry, inequality, average, means

I was discussing means with my friend, and I tried to illustrate the concept of geometric mean using the following idea:

> Suppose we have two positive quantities $x,y>0$. The simplest geometric object we can make out of those is an $x \times y$ rectangle. What if we want a *regular* rectangle (i.e., a square) that "best approximates this rectangle"?

One possibility is a square of side length $$\ell_1 =\frac{x+y}{2} ,$$
keeping the perimeter the same at $2x+2y$. Another candidate is
$$\ell_2 =\sqrt{xy} ,$$
this time keeping the *area* the same at $xy$.

I then realized I can generalize this idea to higher dimensions: If we have three positive numbers $x,y,z>0$, consider a $x \times y \times z$ rectangle, and a cube whose side $\ell$ is to be decided:

- Keeping the 1-dimensional "length-of-the-skeleton" the same we get
  $$4x+4y+4z=12 \ell_1 \implies \ell_1=\frac{x+y+z}{3}. $$
- Keeping the 2-dimensional area of the faces the same we get
  $$2xy+2xz+2yz=6\ell_2^2 \implies \ell_2=\sqrt{\frac{xy+xz+yz}{3}}.$$
- Keeping the 3-dimensional volume the same we get
  $$x y z =\ell_3^3  \implies \ell_3=\sqrt[3]{x y z}.$$

Notice that among the usual arithmetic and geometric means, a different kind of mean has popped up.

This idea can go further, using ["$n$-orthotopes" or hyperrectangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle), producing $n$ distinct means from any sequence $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of positive quantities:

For $1 \leq d \leq n$ let $e_d(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ denote the [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) on $n$ symbols of degree $d$. We define
$$\ell_d(x_1,\dots,x_n) := \sqrt[d]{\frac{e_d(x_1,\dots,x_n)}{\binom{n}{d}}}.$$

I have two questions about this:

1. Is this concept already known?
2. I believe that the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) generalizes to $\ell_1 \geq \ell_2 \geq \cdots \geq \ell_n$. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: In 1979 I found a very nice proof of the Maclaurin's inequality. The idea of the proof you can see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197955/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that relationship between the  elementary symmetric polynomials holds, it is known as [Maclaurin's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality), and a consequence of [Newton's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities).